# Control which cells are static and which iterate on column-wide formulas

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to write a formula for an entire column.

One cell reference should iterate +1 per step down the column and another should not. Every cell reference appears to iterate no matter what I do, however.

```
IF(B2)>0, B2/G22, "")
IF(B3)>0, B3/G22, "")
IF(B4)>0, B4/G22, "")
```

How do I apply this formula to a column without G22 turning into G23, 24, 25?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this somewhere in row 2 (obviously not col B or G):

```
=arrayformula(if((B2:B)>0, B2:B/G22, ""))
```